# Trying to send output to log file with tee using systemd but the log file isn't being created?

Tags: linux, logging, systemd, tee

I want to run a node application via `systemd` and have its output go to both stdout and a log file.  The node app is in the folder named `www/www.appname.com` and I want to have the log file in `www/log.appname.com`.  I have the following service `servicename` defined:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node server | tee -a ../log.appname.com/appname.service.log
KillMode=process
Restart=always
RestartSec=20
WorkingDirectory=/home/username/www/www.appname.com

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

But when I run my service, e.g.

```
systemctl --user restart servicename
```

Then the folder `www/log.appname.com` remains blank, so maybe there's something wrong with the path name I'm using in the `tee`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell command lines are not directly supported. If shell command lines are to be used, they need to be passed explicitly to a shell implementation of some kind. Example:

ExecStart=sh -c 'dmesg | wc'

So try something like

```
ExecStart=sh -c '/usr/bin/node server | tee -a ../log.appname.com/appname.service.log'
```